# How can i select my self made Texture Paint on my Shape in Blender 2.8?

Tags: materials, texture-painting

I have two different Texture Paints in my Material and i dont know how to select one or another. One is automaticly selected and i dont know how to switch them.

[image: Material selecting screen][image: Texture Paint Screen]

Comment: Have you looked at the Shader layout window to see how they are connected as nodes? There should be an image node for each image texture there.

Comment: I tried it out and it worked like a charm thanks alot!

Comment: Hi, MisterSleider. Blender Stack Exchange is a different platform than an online forum - questions here should not be marked as [SOLVED] in the title. Instead there should be an answer posted. It is OK to answer your own question as well if it is partially given in a comment or if it is fully answered in a comment as well if the person commenting was not sure if they had enough information about the issue to post it as an answer. This way it is left for people browsing the internet to find it if they have a similar question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the Shader layout window to see how they are connected as nodes? There should be an image node for each image texture there. – Craig D Jones